# Multiply columns based on the Year and Month

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have the following tables:

BitcoinValue

| Year | Month | Bitcoin Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 4 | $58,726.68 |
| 2021 | 3 | $49,619.64 |

Wallet

| Date | Amount of Bitcoin | From Wallet | To Wallet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| April 6, 2021 | 20 | A | B |
| March 6 2021 | 3 | B | C |

What can I do to add a column that takes the year and month of the date column of wallet and match it to the year and month columns of `BitcoinValue` table, and yield (20 * $58,872.68) for row one? Thanks.

Comment: Use Date.Year() and Date.Month() functions in two custom columns and then merge one table against the other using those two fields

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Power Query Editor** add 2 column **Year** and **Month** to your table **Wallet** as below-

```
Year = Date.Year([Date])
```

```
Month = Date.Month([Date])
```

**Now,** join (left) your wallet table with BitcoinValue table using column Year and Month. You will have all necessary columns/value now in table Wallet from BitcoinValue.