# PowerBI and MAX for Multiplying Values?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

```
log1    
date    cost
15-May  10
18-May  15
17-May  12
    
    
log2    
date    cost
15-May  1
16-May  3
18-May  2
```

What I want to do is create a "curent cost" Measure by finding the latest cost value based on the date in log1 (18-May and $15) and multiply it by the latest cost in log2 (18-May and 2). I then want to put that measure in a simple bar chart with the date, in this example that is 18-May and $30.

I played around with MAX but can't seem to figure this out. Help?

Thanks!

I think this is similar to [Multiply columns based on the Year and Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67541135/multiply-columns-based-on-the-year-and-month) but not sure.

Comment: Do you want to show data only for the 18th of May? Or all the date combinations? What happens when you don't have a matching date? i.e. a missing date in one table but not in another.

Comment: @AngeloCanepa all date combinations. If there is a date match it can be empty for "everything". There should be no date mismatches however. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of output do you need?

```
Measure = 
var maxLog1 = CALCULATE( MAX(Log1[date]), REMOVEFILTERS(Log1[date]))
var maxlog2 = CALCULATE( MAX(log2[date]), REMOVEFILTERS(Log2[date]))

var result = CALCULATE( MAX(Log1[cost]), Log1[date] = maxLog1) * CALCULATE(MAX(log2[cost]), log2[date] = maxlog2)
return
result
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're tables really are that simple, you could use the dax function called lookupvalue
Its similar to a vlookup in excel and you can look up the cost based on the date

So in this example it would be added to the log2 table

```
Amount = 'log2'[cost] * LOOKUPVALUE('log1'[cost],'log1'[date],'log2'[date])
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax

If there was a relationship between the columns on date you'd able able to use the Related() function

Comment: This doesn't produce errors, but does not do the multiplication I expect. Thanks.

Comment: i have revised the answer so that it will multiply it by the log2 cost for you aswell rather than just bringing the log1 cost onto the table

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution, assuming the following:

- There is a unique `cost` per day in each log table
- No empty missing dates, although it doesn't break the calculation.
- The `Calendar` Table stores the dates.

### Data Model

[image]

### Calendar Table: Calculation

```
Calendar =
CALENDAR (
    MIN ( MIN ( log1[date] ), MIN ( log2[date] ) ),
    MAX ( MAX ( log1[date] ), MAX ( log2[date] ) )
)
```

### Calculation: Measure

This calculation is dependant of using  `Calendar[Date]` as the central `Date` value in your visuals.

```
Cost = sum(log1[cost])*sum(log2[cost])
```

### Output 1

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to create a calculation that's independent of having date as part of the visual and retrieve the right totals.

```
CostSumx = 
sumx('Calendar',RELATED('log1'[cost])*RELATED(log2[cost]))
```

This means you need to change your relationships to 1:1 and `BOTH`

[image]

### Output 2

[image]

### Tables

#### log1

| date | cost |
| --- | --- |
| 15 May 2021 | 20 |
| 16 May 2021 | 30 |
| 17 May 2021 | 40 |

#### log2

| date | cost |
| --- | --- |
| 15 May 2021 | 1 |
| 16 May 2021 | 2 |
| 17 May 2021 | 3 |

Comment: I am not able to restructure the entire data environment. Azure Functions are pumping data into Cosmos DB, so the level-of-effort to completely change the platform is not possible in this case. PowerBI was chosen because it can abstract-away the data and handle presentation. Thanks.